# Can I assign my own media id to jwplayer through API

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

I have a small "Java" Program which uploads the video to Jw player via API.

Is there any way to send media id along with video?

I mean Can I use my media id instead of generated media id? Or is there any way so that i can assign my media id to jwplaye through API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When uploading content to JW Platform, the mediaid is always auto-generated (you cannot assign your own mediaid). This is to avoid conflicting unique identifiers. However, you can add a custom parameter at videos/create or videos/update if you have another unique identifier that you would like to assign to the video.

The custom parameter is accessible and searchable, so for example, if you create a custom parameter of `legacy id`, you can then access `item.legacy_id`.

Documentation: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/reference/v1/methods/videos/create.html

Note that `video key` in the API documentation is the same as `mediaid` on the dashboard.